# need software for unknown audio format

Tags: audio, file-format

I extracted some files from an old Dos game for Nitemare 3d and identified them as .VOC audio and .MID, the Windows version has the same midi, and some strange format I can't figure out, importing it as raw data gives me high pitched garbage, is anyone familiar with this format?

[The audio file](http://bbqgiraffegames.com/Files/UnknownFormat.BS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Audacity. https://www.audacityteam.org/

Import as raw 8-bit file.

Comment: yeah my dumbass tried that and it came out sounding like garbage so i thought it wasn't raw until I realized it was just playing really fast